# Properly piping Items to external programs (native utilities) in one go?

Tags: powershell

I've reading about Functions/Adcanced Functions, while there is allot of information on how to handle incoming pipeline data there seems to be little information on how to properly forward data to external programs (native utilities)

I am writting a general purpose file searching function, it works exactly like [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf):

- Search Everything GUI window comes up to make a selection,
- Everything is closed, focus returns to Powershell
- Selected objects should be passed to the pipeline, one a time

After seeking advice on how to best approach this on [Reddit - Powershell](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/yr7369/event_driven_powershell_script_that_needs_to_wait/), I decided to go with dumping selected objects paths from Everything to a text file:

```
function EverythingShell {

    Begin {

    Ditto /Disconnect   #Turn of Ditto Clipboard Monitoring

    Clear-Content -Path "C:\TEMP\EverythingShell Paths.txt" #Empty out any previous path entries

    Start-Process "C:\TEMP\EverythingShell.ahk"      #Bring up Everything GUI Window

    Write-host "Loading..."

    }

    Process {

    while ($EverythingShellPaths -eq $null){

        $EverythingShellPaths = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\EverythingShell Paths.txt"

        If($EverythingShellPaths -eq $null){

        }

        Else{

            Ditto /Connect #Turn back on Ditto Clipboard Monitoring

            ."C:\TEMP\Kill - EverythingShell.ahk" #Exit EverythingShell.ahk script

            $EverythingShellPaths = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\EverythingShell Paths.txt" # Read any new path entries

            Write-Output $EverythingShellPaths #Pipe out the path entries one at a time

        }}

    }
}
```

When I pipe the functions results to Powershell commandlets (or even my own functions) it works as  I expect it to:

```
EverythingShell | Get-Item

    Directory: C:\TEMP

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/11/2022    14:37       37964907 1-08 Dollars And Cents.flac
-a---          11/11/2022    14:37       21820061 1-06 No Surprises.flac
-a---          11/11/2022    14:37       10588866 09 Polyethylene, Pts. 1 & 2.mp3
-a---          11/11/2022    14:37        5262364 10 Melatonin.mp3
```

But when I pipe it to an external program such as [foobar2000](https://www.foobar2000.org/), a audio player, it breaks.
Invoking `EverythingShell | foobar2000.exe` , first launches Foobar2000s window, then followed by Everythings window. I am expecting it to be in reverse:

- Everything Window Opens, Closes, focus is then returned back to Powershell
- Items are  read from `EverythingShell Paths.txt`

Finally, Foobar2000.exe is launched with the  items piped to it  as a single collection.

This is exactly how `FZF | foobar2000.exe` works.  Only after  a selection in the FZF TUI is made, foobar2000.exe is launched with the items selected.
Even if I do something like, Foobar window opens with the two audio files playing:

```
$var = "C:\Temp\Radiohead Live- Kid A\1-06 No Surprises.flac", "C:\Temp\Radiohead Live- Kid A\1-08 Dollars And Cents.flac"

foobar2000.exe $var
```

In short, how can I get my function to act like FZF, (`FZF | foobar2000.exe` ) only launching the external program at the final step and sending selected items to it, as one collection.

Any help would be truelly appreciated here, scratching my head for 10 hours straight.

---

Edit1:
@I tried out @JosefZ's suggestion of `$var | foobar2000.exe`, Intrestingly enough, it did not work. Foobar opens but no files are loaded, Whereas `foobar2000.exe $var` works as expected.

I also tried, @Doug Maurer suggestion, `(EverythingShell) | foobar2000.exe` Foobar opens first, when the prompt also returns, nothing is loaded into Foobar. I tried the following `foobar2000.exe (EverythingShell)`, It works. Foobar does not open until the promt returns, when it opens, files are also loaded.

`<Function call> | <Open Application>`
In the above example, why is Powershell executing to the right of the pipe first, then the left. should it not first execute all the steps on the left, then procced to the right?

Comment: Would `$var | foobar2000.exe` work? The same as `foobar2000.exe $var`?

Comment: what about `(EverythingShell) | foobar2000.exe`  or `$output = EverythingShell; $output | foobar200.exe`

Comment: As an aside: Your `while ($EverythingShellPaths -eq $null)` loop is creating a tight loop; you should sleep between checks.

Comment: @JosefZ I placed the answer to your question in the OP.

Comment: @DougMaurer `$output = EverythingShell; $output | foobar200.exe` that did not cause Foobar to open early but when it did no files were loaded into it. your other suggestion, did not work, its reverse order did though, please take a look at my Edit in OP.

Comment: @mklement0 good idea! I implemented that now